# Как отправить json запросом post?

Tags: java

Добрый день, подскажите пытаюсь отправить json для этого использую данную конструкцию

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    jsonObject.put("name", "foo");
    jsonObject.put("num", new Integer(100));
    jsonObject.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
    jsonObject.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));

 StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    jsonObject.writeJSONString(out);



    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost http = new HttpPost(url);

    List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", out.toString()));
    http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    String response = (String) client.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());
    System.out.println(response);
```

но сервер пишет

```
{"error":{"id":3,"text":"no param name, no param num, no param balance,  no param is_vip"}}
```

в чём причина ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: jsonBody за что отвечает ?

Comment: Странно, у меня работает - в теле запроса, содержится содержимое json. JsonBody это ваш json преобразованный в строку

Comment: А может быть причина в сервере ?

Comment: @VargSieg я не совсем понимаю, что за параметры и каким образом вы пытаетесь их передать. И какую роль во всем этом играет json отправляемый в теле запроса.

Comment: Параметры типа String предать POST запросом на сервер можно без json. Просто что бы сервер их принял я понять не могу в чём у меня ошибка ?

Comment: @VargSieg а причем здесь тогда json. Если вы передаете параметры то они кодируются в теле запроса, то что делает ваш код указаный в вопросе. Если вы еще хотите и json передать то у вас ничего не выйдет, т.к. тело запроса уже используется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48610/discussion-between-varg-sieg-and-artem-konovalov).